# How to get the page view count of a web page from its URL?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, pageviews

**CONTEXT**
My client needs their site and its functionalities migrated from Wordpress to Hubspot. Because this site is hosted on Hubspot, there aren't really any options for server-side functionality. What I need to build is a home page that displays "cards" for each blog post, the "card" will display info about the blog post (page view, share count etc.) and will be hyperlinked to the blog post itself. What I need to figure out how to do is how to use client side scripting (javascript) to grab the hyperlink of each "card" and use it to find out what the page view count for the linked-page is so I can display it on the card.

**MY EXPERIENCE/STRUGGLES**
I've looked pretty heavily into using Google Analytic's API to accomplish this. The problem I've had is that it seems like GA is only good for tracking the current page. You throw in the GA js into each page and then can view it in the GA dashboard. I haven't found anything about using it to get analytics for external pages.

**WHAT I HOPE TO FIND**
A plugin or javascript technique that allows me to feed a function a URL parameter and that returns the page view count for that URL, plain and simple.

If any additional information would help you help me let me know.

Comment: There isn't anything you can do to get the page count of external sites. Most traffic analytics come from either reading from server log files or by putting something (like google analytics) on each page that will log the visit to some other system.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've found with GA. I was hoping there was a way I could associate that information with the page's URL then grab it from another page using the URL.